# Where to change HTTP port setting in Masonite?

Tags: python-3.x, masonite

When I run `craft serve` and it serves the web pages on `8000` port.

Is there any setting where I can change the port so I can run the server on `3000` Port or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If that port is blocked you can specify a port by running:
>
> ```
> $ craft serve --port 8080
> ```
>
> <sub>[Source](https://github.com/MasoniteFramework/masonite#installation-1)</sub>

So just use:

```
craft serve --port 3000
```

Comment: Maybe someone else can improve this answer by specifying how to make the change permanent. I tried to update the .env file, but that alone wasn't enough; and I'm new to masonite